# <c:url> tag is rendering relative urls into the output

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a JSP application, in which I am using the following to generate a url:

```
            <c:url value="/import" var="url">
              <c:param name="type" value="${type}"/>
              <c:param name="src" value="${source.title}"/>
            </c:url>

            <h2><a href="${url}">${source.title}</a></h2>
```

However, this is generating urls of the form:

```
a href="//import?type=DEFAULT&src=xml
```

instead of

`a href="http://localhost/import?type=DEFAULT&src=xml`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I am running the following configuration:

- Tomcat7
- Servlet 3.0
- jsp 1.2.1

EDIT:

I should point out that this was working fine with tomcat5.5. I am trying to port my app to use tomcat7, which is causing this to break.

Comment: Nothing's wrong. That's normal and expected (except fo the double `/`). The `http://localhost` part in useless.

Comment: But that url is invalid. I expect either a relative url to be rendered ( /import?type=DEFAULT&src=xml ) or an absolute url.

Comment: So, it's the double / that bothers you, right? Not the absence of `http://localhost`. How did you specify the context path of the app? How did you deploy it?

Comment: It is deployed in a tomcat7 container using context path "/".

Comment: Have you tried specifying the context path as the empty string?